# Zmq Context - Should I create another context in a new thread?

Tags: c++, zeromq

I've got several server apps that use a shared ZMQ class I created. Occasionally when these servers process a request, they need to send a message to another ZMQ server. I'm fairly new to ZMQ so I wanted to make sure I understand this correctly.

The class that handles the server listener creates a `zmq::context_t` and `zmq::socket_t`, and binds the socket. This runs on a separate thread infinitely. When this server needs to send a message in another function ( completely torn-off from this ZMQ class ), would I need to generate a new context here and send the message, or should I somehow pass down the same context to this class ( on a different thread ), bind a new socket then go from there?

If the former, does it matter what number I use to initialize the new context, or is **`context( 1 )`** fine? There's a part in the guide that says creating a second context is like having multiple instances of ZMQ, which I don't think really matters since its only being used to send a file then closing. But I'm probably wrong?

Comment: I cannot tell what is the better practice, but the [docs](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq#toc3) say: »A ØMQ context is thread safe and may be shared among as many application threads as necessary, without any additional locking required on the part of the caller.«

Comment: The `context` ought never be a "consumable/disposable", it has a lot of overhead associated with its instantiation. The number of **`IOthreads`** is another story -- more related with achieving a minimum latency, blocking-state robustness and data-pumping performance ( or performance-class based grouping ). See **`ZMQ_AFFINITY`** used for mapping of individual socket(s) onto respective `IOthread`-#(s). High-performance + low-latency code simply has to tweak these internalities to the max. **`inproc://`** transport-class is IO-less & may use an instance of **`context( 0 )`** it is a memory map.

Comment: @HenriMenke you might be interested in ZeroMQ, being a **principally locking-free mental concept** as the underlying services handle all that automatically. ZeroMQ has set a remarkable yardstick for distributed computing by a few of its maxims -- ZeroCopy, ZeroSharing, ZeroLocking, (almost) ZeroLatency :o) et al -- Pieter Hintjens' book "Code Connected, Volume 1." seems to be a bible for any advanced signalling / messaging in distributed systems. Worth a time & effort to read it ( pdf available too ).

Comment: I didn't realize the context # was the IOThreads at first, thought it had something to do with the context identifier since there is a set IOThreads function as well. But I'm working on modifying our apps to all use pointers to the main context now. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: a single instance of **`context`**, with a single I/O thread, is probably what you need.  In more detail:

[Per the docs](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq) the context is thread safe.  Note that the original 0MQ *sockets* generally are not ( with having some newer, drafted, ones designed so as they become such ).

From the [FAQ](http://zeromq.org/area:faq):

> #### What is the optimal number of I/O threads for best performance?
>
> The basic heuristic is to allocate 1 I/O thread in the context for every gigabit per second of data that will be sent and received ( aggregated ). 
>    Further, the number of I/O threads should not exceed ( number_of_cpu_cores - 1 ).

Another thing to note is **`inproc://`** transport-class sockets [must be created in the same context.](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-inproc)

Unless you're transferring multiple gigabits/sec, I recommend a single context for your entire process with a single I/O thread.

Also as a guideline, the 0MQ context is intended to be "long-lived".  It would be unusual to create/destroy multiple contexts in a single run of an application.  This is generally true of 0MQ sockets, too.  If you are creating/destroying many sockets you may have taken the wrong approach.

Comment: There new thread safe sockets. But there in draft stage for now.

Comment: what about sockets? is it better to save them or to make a new one often? I have zmq sending messages within a function that gets called every some ms - e.g. 50 or 100